# Histogram equalization upon RGB images? RGB ouput possible?

Tags: image-processing, boost, rgb, yuv, boost-gil

I was writing code for histogram equalization upon RGB images?

It was suggested not performing equalization operation against R-G-B channels respectively.
So I first converted RGB to YUV color space and then performed equalization on Y channel (only), leaving U and V channel as what they were, converted altered Y channel with original U and V channels back to RGB color space.

The (RGB) resulting output was not ideal, while the gray scale ouput generated from Y channel only was quite acceptable.

My question is, Is it possible to get a full color RGB equalized ouput? And how? Should I perform equalization operation on U&V channel as well?

Comment: _[GIL currently provides the following color spaces: gray_t, rgb_t, rgba_t, and cmyk_t.](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/gil/doc/html/gildesignguide.html#ColorSpaceSectionDG)_

Comment: you are right, so i have to hard-code the color-space-conversion for YUV